# Makefile with multiple dependencies in directory tree

Tags: makefile, debian

Even there are a lot of topics in this area, I can't found a solution.
I want to combine two technics in a GNU make Makefile to create several Debian packages out of the directory trees with files:

1. Create a Debian package depending from a tree of files in the according direcotry e.g. a.deb depends from all files within the directory a/, so if a/foo/bar was changed, a.deb will be generated
2. Do this for multiple packages with the same building rule and actions e.g. the target a.deb depends from the files-tree in the directory a/, b.deb from b/ until z.deb from z/

The following looks fine, but it don't find the prerequisite files:

```
TARGETS = a.deb b.deb z.deb
all: $(TARGETS)
%.deb: $(shell find % -type f)
$(TARGETS):
   @echo "#### Building $@ due to \"$?\" ####"
```

For testing purpose only, I've tested the rule with a simple "echo" instead of the "find", this worked fine (but of course only depend the target from the directory, not the full file-tree):

```
TARGETS = a.deb b.deb z.deb
all: $(TARGETS)
%.deb: $(shell echo %/ )
$(TARGETS):
   @echo "#### Building $@ due to \"$?\" ####"
```

If I hardcode the target filename into the rule inside the "find", it works:

```
TARGETS = a.deb b.deb z.deb
all: $(TARGETS)
a.deb: $(shell find a/ -type f)
b.deb: $(shell find b/ -type f)
z.deb: $(shell find z/ -type f)
$(TARGETS):
   @echo "#### Building $@ due to \"$?\" ####"
```

But now I have to maintain changes in the package name or adding new packages at 3 places within the file to keep it consistent.

Maintaining the makefile is annoying and dangerous, is there any better way?

`

Comment: A possible different approach would be if you had all files under version control, and were not adding any new files. Then you could set up your version control system to commit new changes automatically, and run your Debian package builds as part of the post-commit hook.

Comment: Oh, what a good proposal: Yes, all files are under Git version control too, so there should be an option to trigger a Debian package build on commit. This would need a change in working behavior, because currently I have several commits until one package release happens... buh, I have to think... Thanks anyhow!

Comment: if you think it is useful, I can make it a formal answer. I was imagining a scenario where you had multiple repositories, but that would depend on the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think a formal answer is not needed, because it is more a workaround / better approach completely omitting the Makefile. The underlying Makefile problem is still open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solutions reveal a misunderstanding of how make evaluates variables and functions.  You must understand that make proceeds in two distinct steps: first, it parses all the makefiles and constructs an internal database of the variables and rules that were defined.  Second, after all makefiles are parsed, it goes through the relevant targets and tries to build the ones that are out of date.  Importantly, all expansion of variables and functions in both the *target* and *prerequisite* parts of a rule happen during the first step: parsing the makefiles.  On the other hand, patterns are not expanded until the second step: building the targets (because it's not until we try to build targets that we actually can match patterns against what we want to build).

So, this:

```
%.deb: $(shell find % -type f)
```

will run the literal shell function `find % -type f` and then use the output of that function as the prerequisite list for the pattern `%.dep`.  Since you almost certainly don't have any file or directory named, literally, `%`, the result of this find command is empty and there are no prerequisites defined.

At the same time this:

```
%.deb: $(shell echo %/ )
```

Is just a really slow, badly-performing way to write:

```
%.deb: %/
```

Why invoke a shell just to echo a static string?

To make this work you need to use some aspect of [metaprogramming](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/).  For example, you can use [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
TARGETS = a.deb b.deb z.deb

all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): $$(shell find $$(patsubst %.deb,%,$$@)/ -type f)
        @echo "#### Building $@ due to \"$?\" ####"
```

Comment: How the hell do you as "MadScientist" know about Secondary expansion??? I'm within IT since more than 20 years, also working with Makefiles a lot, but this is really new for me.... I've tried it and it worked out of the box - thanks a lot for this really good hint. BTW: using $(shell echo %/ ) was of course only for testing purpose, to see whether the % will be expanded to a command inside a shell - and this worked. Additionally I learned a lot by your explanation, thanks

Comment: The `%` wasn't expanded "inside the shell" at all.  The `$(shell echo %/)` simply invoked a shell with the literal command `echo %/`, which printed the literal string`%/`, and so `%/` was used as the prerequisite.